# Swift: Next instance of certain time on soonest date

Tags: swift, date, time, nsdate

I'm working with Swift 2.1 to build an app that sets repeated reminders. This consists mainly of two parts:

1. The user can select a time at which reminders must begin (e.g. 09:00)
2. The user can choose to have it repeat every X hours (e.g. if it's six hours, then the reminders would be set at 09:00, 15:00, 21:00, 03:00)

I'm using [CVCalendarKit](https://github.com/Dwive/CVCalendarKit) to manipulate certain date units, so part 2 (adding X hours every time) isn't the trouble I'm having.

What I'm trying to figure out is if there's an easy way to create an instance of `NSDate` with the soonest instance of a certain time.

So, assuming today is 13th of February 2016,

- If it's 8:59, the `NSDate` created should be `2016-02-13 09:00:00`
- If it's 9:01, the `NSDate` created should be `2016-02-14 09:00:00`

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NSCalendar.nextDateAfterDate()`

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

let now = NSDate()

let nextTime = calendar.nextDateAfterDate(now,
                          matchingHour: 9,
                                minute: 0,
                                second: 0,
                               options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchNextTime)
```

If you aren't using the open source Swift Foundation libraries, this only works on iOS 8+ or OS X 10.9+

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for changes in daylight savings time.

Quite soon there will a day where one hour is missing. In that case you (or your user) must make two decisions: 1. What happens if the date you are interested in doesn't exist? (For example, there will be one day in the year in the UK where "2:30 am on the next day" doesn't exist). 2. What do you mean by "every six hours"? On one day of the year, "6 hours after 21:00" is "04:00" on the next day.

Comment: This probably should have been a comment. There's no real answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. :) I'll be sure to take that into consideration.